# Extract day and time from Howard Hinnant's date library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std

I am using Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, cross-platform, C++11/14 timezone library:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::make_zoned("Europe/Rome", std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

And I am getting an output like this:

```
2017-11-29 16:24:32.710766 CET
```

Is it possible from *zoned_time* to extract the day (for example: Monday) and the HH:MM in diffent strings? Can the *zoned_time* be converted to struct tm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
date::format("%A", date::make_zoned("Europe/Rome", std::chrono::system_clock::now())
```

That gives the day of the week.  See more format strings here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

The default you get without `date::format()` is `%F %T %Z`.

Comment: There can be minor differences/enhancements between the strftime flags and the ones in my lib.  I gave up on importing the definitions of these flags by reference.  So here's the official list: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#to_stream_formatting

Comment: Example code for interfacing with the C API: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#Ccompatiblity